# 403 Error response from single URI request?

Tags: ruby, espn

When trying the live API explorer and using my api key I can get a good response.  However when using the same URI link generated from the explorer within my application, I get a 403 error.  However, the application makes only 1 request.

```
url = URI.parse("http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/athletes/355?
apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")  
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
puts res.body
```

Here's the response in the terminal:

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "code": 403,
  "message" : "Account Inactive"
}
```

403 should mean I'm exceeding my limit, but the message says Account Inactive.  This is a new account and I got confirmation that it was active. Plus my API key works in the web interface.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you're only using the path from the URI string and not passing the query parameters as well in your GET call.